# Unity3D ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with my code. Compiler stop on this line when I try to pick up the object.

```
ekwipunek.ListaNaszychPrzedmiotow[i] = BazaDanych_Eq.ListaPrzedmiotow [IdPrzedmiotu];
```

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

```
if ( Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Q))
{
    IdPrzedmiotu = DoPodniesienia.GetComponent<PrzedmiotPodniesienie>().id;
    for (int i = 0; i < ekwipunek.ListaNaszychPrzedmiotow.Count; i++)
    {
        if (ekwipunek.ListaNaszychPrzedmiotow[i].id == 0 && DoPodniesienia != null)
        {
            ekwipunek.ListaNaszychPrzedmiotow[i] = BazaDanych_Eq.ListaPrzedmiotow [IdPrzedmiotu];
            Destroy(DoPodniesienia);
            DoPodniesienia = null;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: As a side note: I appreciate the effort to write your post in English. However, Stackoverflow is generically an English speaking site, so your code might be confusing or obfuscated (unclear or illegible) if it is written in a different language. This is only for your own future use in case you have more in-depth questions.

Comment: Thank you and sorry but it was my first post here. Next time I will write my code in English.

Comment: Like I said, you are free to write your code in your language preference. I wanted to give you a tip for the future just in case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem, more than likely, exists because one of your indices on this line references something that would be outside of the range of the collection.

You're setting this variable that is used as an index to an id.

```
 IdPrzedmiotu = DoPodniesienia.GetComponent<PrzedmiotPodniesienie>().id;
```

Then, you're referencing it further down without verifying that it is available in your collection.

```
 BazaDanych_Eq.ListaPrzedmiotow [IdPrzedmiotu]
```

You need to validate this value or this collection before accessing it.

---

## Future Debugging Tip: `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

- Check the count of any collection you are using
- Check the value of any index you will use to reference the collection

---

```
public class YourClass
{
    ...
    Debug.Log($"The collection \"ListaNaszychPrzedmiotow\" is {ListaNaszychPrzedmiotow.Count()}");
    Debug.Log($"The index value of \"i\" is {i}");
    ...
}
```